# Show and hide title bar during lifecycle

Tags: android, layout

I've used

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

to hide the title bar from my app.........
This is working fine, but now, in the same activity and in the same layout, I need to activate it when a button is pressed. Can I do that? I've tried but return a exception cause :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23656): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

How I can workaround that?

Answer (score 0):

on button click
For Hiding:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

For Showing:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and call `setContentView()` then everytime

Comment: call these lines on button click and then call setContentView(your layout's id here)